# Language that embraces mutable state?

Tags: language-design, immutability

There seems to be a trend towards immutable objects, and pure functional programming. While I recognize the benefits, I find it hard to apply these principles to GUI programming, for example. But I also find classical imperative languages with mutable objects lacking. I was wondering whether there is a language or system that *embraces* mutable state, and makes it especially easy to work with.

Below are some features I would consider to be "designed around mutability":

- The ability to hook up events and get a change notification for any variable. It would make it very easy to write GUIs and MVC applications. And you could just make a `List<MyObject>`, and stuff it into a list widget, and with a bit of configuration it would manage your list for you, no manual listview.insert() etc..
- A type system that considers state. For example, If I pass a `Car` into a function that requires a working one, the compiler should try to proove that `car.broken == False`. If it can't proove it, it won't compile, and I have to ensure it (by putting the code in an `if` block, or setting it manually to False).
- A take on concurrency that makes sense for mutable objects. For example an `atomic` statement, that guarantees that certain statements are run together, using transactions or locks. The goal is not performance, but ease of use and GUI responsiveness. I should be able to manipulate data and the GUI from any thread, using `atomic {step1; step2}` to ensure invariants.

I'm not looking for a system with these *exact* features, but one written in a similar spirit. The closest I've seen to this is C#/.NET with its data binding features.

Gtk+ has custom ListModels that keep a GtkTreeView in like with your data without manual inserts/updates. Android has ListAdapters which are similar. I haven't found a thread-safe GUI, but you can get pretty close with a liberal use of `Invoke()` in C#/WinForms, or `gobject_idle_add` in Gtk+. Are there any systems like what I describe? Or research material, references, etc.?

Comment: You might find [Functional Reactive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming) interesting.

Comment: I once wrote a language called [Hap](https://github.com/evincarofautumn/Hap) that includes some of these concepts—reacting to changing expressions, evaluating things `atomic`ally, and so forth. Though I never got around to implementing a typechecker for it. I don’t maintain it, but you may find it interesting.

Comment: By definition, OOP languages _are_ languages that embrace mutable state. It is not a coincidence OOP as a programming paradigm arose simultaneously with GUIs (the Smalltalk programming environment). The challenge with OOP is proper software design (choosing lifetime of objects, which objects control what, and deciding what should and should not be mutable), which unfortunately far too many developers are hardly familiar with.

Answer (score 9):

No language have all the properties you describe for very good reasons.

**Change Notifications** The main problem with is the overhead added to the system. Some versions of Smalltalk, for example, supported this. Other versions claimed lack of support of this as a significant performance feature. As you mention C# has `INotifyPropertyChange` but that must be manually implemented. Other systems have similar notification manual patterns for this. JavaScript ECMA 6's `Observe` specification is the latest attempt to do this for all mutable objects in a language.

This will not be mainstream until the underlying performance problems can be addressed in a way that is predictable and understandable.

**Dependency Types** Enforcing predicates such as "car.broken == False" is generally referred to as a dependency type system; a type system that depends on runtime properties of the candidate elements of the type. In general, this has been demonstrated to have polynomial-time complexity. There are some subsets of the general case that can be implemented in linear time but no mainstream language has such a thing. [The SAL annotations by Microsoft are the closest I have seen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235402.aspx) though there might be others I am not aware of.

This will not be mainstream until the underlying principles and limitations of such a type system can be understood without a doctorate in type systems.

**Concurrency Primitives** Concurrency primitives of which `atomic` is a part is a hotly debated topic in languages. Each language has been adapted, in some respects, to allow for concurrency (except JavaScript which is a mutable state language which has explicitly taken a position against shared memory concurrency). There are several languages that have `atomic` in one form or another but differ in how they implement it. Unfortunately, there is no wide consensus on what the "right" solution to this problem is. The mainstream thought is tending to non-mutable shared state as the current savior, hence the ascendancy of functional languages, but which is outside the scope of this question.

This will not be mainstream until the ramifications and limitations of the primitives are understood and either accepted or demonstrated they can do better than atomic writes/shared locks that predominates today shared state concurrency models. This might never be mainstream as other models (such as functional) might prove more fruitful.

Comment: If regards things which have shared mutable state as entities, then there are two ways of mutably encapsulating *values*: with a reference to an unshared mutable object, or a mutable reference to a shareable object that never changes.  Immutable types are fine for things which need to be shared, but using them for things which are not shared is wasteful.  I'd like to see languages/compilers/frameworks give more attention toward interoperability of mutable unshared objects and immutable but shareable ones.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difficulty I see with mutability in many programming languages, and part of the reason for the trend toward immutable objects, is that many languages and frameworks make no distinction between mutable values, immutably-encapsulated values, and entities.  A variable of type `int[]` may always, if non-null, hold a reference to a heap object instance of type `int[]`, but there are at least four different ways in which that variable might encapsulate state:

- It might identify an unshared array, whose owner is apt to mutate it as it sees fit, and serve to encapsulates the array's contents on behalf of the owner.
- It might identify a array which is shared with code that agrees never to modify it, and serve to encapsulate the array's contents on behalf of anyone with a reference.
- It might identify an array which is owned by some other object, and encapsulates a "connection" with the object that owns the array
- It might identify an array which is owned by the same object as the reference, but to which other references may exist, and encapsulates both the contents of the array and a "connection" with other objects holding references.

An array which will never be modified is effectively a value, as is an array to which no references will exist outside its owner [if an object holds the only reference to a collection, things in that collection which cannot be accessed but through that reference are considered "inside" the owner of the reference].  If multiple independent references exist to an array, and its value may be modified, then it is an entity.

Often times, it's desirable to make sure things will behave as values; having values accidentally turn into entities is apt to cause bugs.  Making sure that something will behave as a value will require ensuring that either it never change, or else that all references to it will be contained within a single "owner".  Unshared values are often very useful and efficient types to work with; unfortunately, none of the Java-inspired languages I'm aware of seem to recognize them as a concept and provide the tools necessary to work with them while ensuring that they don't accidentally "leak" and turn into entities.

When you talk about attaching change notifications to things, it seems like you're leaning toward an "everything is an entity" philosophy.  I really wouldn't recommend such a thing; while change notifications can be good, having everything be a fully-mutable entity can quickly turn into a mess (e.g. if `ObservedObject` is itself a mutable property, and if another object might want to know if the particular entity identified by `ObservedObject` changes, what should it do if `ObservedObject` itself changes so as to identify a different entity?)  It's far better to minimize the number of points at which entities are attached to each other.